# How to convert a string to a specific DateTime format in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

How to convert the string `"28/09/2009"` to `DateTime` in a specific format?
Ex:
 I want to convert "2009-09-28 17:30:40" to DateTime.
 I want to convert "28/09/2009 17:30:40" to DateTime.
 I want to convert "20090928 17:30:40" to DateTime.

There are multiple possible formats. I tried this:

```
string[] formats = new string[] {"yyyymmdd","yyyymmddThhmmss","yyyy/mm/dd  hh:mm:ss","yyyy/mm/dd","yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss","yyyy-mm-dd"};
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(aDate, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This example throws an exception with the message "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

What's wrong in the code above?

Comment: Falaí brazuca! :) Can you give us a little more information on your scenario? Do you receive dates in all three formats withing the same context?

Comment: Fala aí.... I need to read an xml document. In this document there are strings that represent dates. But these dates can be in multiple formats. I have to identify these formats and convert the strings to DateTime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of your formats put the day first, like this: `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Also note the capital 'M', since lower case 'm' is for 'minutes'.  You have a similar problem with your hours; since your samples all use 24 hour time you need a capital 'H'.

Your format string array should look like this:

```
string[] formats = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"};
```

Those formats exactly match your supplied sample strings.

Additionally, you probably want to use the invariant culture rather than `en-US` in this case.  Otherwise, the '/' character in your format strings is really a culture-specific date separator, which a user might over-ride on their local system.

Finally, since you're obviously having trouble matching up the strings up, you might want to use `TryParseExact()`, which works just like parse exact but uses an `out` parameter rather than returning the value, so that it can return a boolean to indicate success or failure rather than throwing an exception.

See the complete format string reference here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx