# C# Best method to convert custom String to DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

What's the best method for converting a custom string to DateTime format?

My custom strings could look any of these...
"5d 4h 25m", "4h 25m", or "25m"

Comment: You want to convert something like "5d 4h 25m" to a DateTime object? Or you mean TimeSpan?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489424/how-convert-an-string-to-an-specific-datetime-format-in-c/1489462#1489462

Comment: Those are TimeSpan, not valid DateTime string representations (no year, month, day, etc); it should be converted to a TimeSpan object.

Answer (score 1):

You can set any pattern you like and use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse your string to a DateTime object.

You might want to take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

`var converted = Convert.ToDateTime(yourString);`

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to store each components individually, you could use TimeSpan.

here is a link with details about TimeSpan: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan-parse

On a second note, i would be telling you to create a method that takes your string and splits it in its various components and use each components with DateTime or TimeSpan