# How to convert string to a particular DateTime format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Hi I'm converting a string to `DateTime` variable but getting exception.
Please tell me what is wrong in this method?

```
string str = "24-04-2014T15:18:18";
DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Exception is:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Why is the string called str and you pass stime?

Comment: You have a format string that starts `yyyy-` and a specific string that obviously doesn't start with a 4 digit year. Do you really not see the problem yourself?

Comment: I think there is a step missing here.  If I understand correctly, the goal is to change the format of the string from dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to a specific DateTime format in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489424/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-specific-datetime-format-in-c)

Comment: I think you have a (common) confusion that `DateTime`s, in and of themselves, have a format. They don't. They don't remember how they were created, and internally they're just a count of a number of (small) intervals that have happened since some fixed point in the past. In the same way that, if we were to measure your height, we could store that, as, say, the number of millimetres you are in height, and not care that the original measurement was done in centimetres or inches. When we turn it back into a string, you need to specify, *at that point*, what measurement system you want to use.

Answer (score 7):

Use `dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss` format instead. Your string and format doesn't match exactly.

From [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

```
string str = "24-04-2014T15:18:18";
DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str,
                                    "dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/EnGUj0)</kbd>.

By the way, I think your `stime` should be `str` :)

Comment: Damn, you answered in less than a minute + 1

Answer (score 2):

OK, so if I am understanding the question, I think this is what you need:

```
string str = "24-04-2014T15:18:18";
DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string stime = dtStartDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

This will take the text from the first format and give you the second format.

Comment: I think you have got my question right. But getting the same DateTime when I convert this string to DateTime.
string str = "24-04-2014T15:18:18";
                DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string stime = dtStartDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

                //DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime dtDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: The idea behind this is that the DateTime will be the same but in a different text format.  If you want to change the DateTime in the middle, manipulate dtStartDateTime with one of its functions.